# MS-DOS 8.0: Determine String Length?

Tags: string, dos

Using MS-DOS 8.0, what is the best way to determine the length of a string?

I looked through Computer Hope (http://www.computerhope.com/msdos.htm), but no commands jumped out at me...

Is there a built in command or must a function be built to address this?

Thanks a ton.

Comment: I don't think this answers your question specifically (see Preet Sangha's excellent answer), but for other string manipulation tasks in DOS, you'll probably find it on this website: http://www.dostips.com/DtTipsStringOperations.php

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [here](http://www.computing.net/answers/dos/length-of-a-string-in-a-batch-file/13650.html) I got and example and this is it cleaned up a litte

```
@echo off
setlocal
set #=%1
set length=0
:loop
if defined # (set #=%#:~1%&set /A length += 1&goto loop)
echo %1 is %length% characters long!
endlocal
```

[image]

Comment: Great example of why we should never script in DOS.  :-)

Answer (score 2):

Here's another option. Pass the string as a paramter like this:

```
   LEN "this is a long string"
```

Here's the code:

```
   @echo off

   echo.%~1>len
   for %%a in (len) do set /a len=%%~za -2

   echo %len%
```

Copy and paste the code into Notepad and save it as LEN.BAT.

NOTE: The fullstop following the ECHO statement is vital should a NUL string be entered. The -2 is required because ECHO automatically adds a CR & LF at the end of each line.

Answer (score 1):

I regularly use the following method:

```
   @echo off
   set str=This is a line of text

   echo.%str%>len
   for %%a in (len) do set /a len=%%~za -2

   echo %len%
```